# How I can configure admin component to show that fields with `name_convertion` from `personName` to `person_name`

Tags: api-platform.com

I have a problem with `name_convertion` and `Admin Component`

When I turn on `name_converter` to `name_converter: 'Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter'` as documentation says ( `https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization#name-conversion` ), in api response I see properies like that: `person_name`, instead defined in entity: `personName` and its ok, but admin component won't show that fields ( `person_name` ):(

When I turned off, in API response I see `personName` and admin component show that fields

Where/or how I can configure admin to show that fields?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug. It has been fixed in API Platform Core (the server-side component) 2.2.6 (released today!): https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1919

Upgrading should fix this problem. If it's not the case, please open an issue.